# transforming a thread blocking to non thread blocking in f#

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

I retrieve data from the Bloomberg API, and am quite surprised by the slowness.
My computation is IO bounded by this.

Therefore I decided to use some async monad builder to unthrottle it.
Upon running it, the results are not so much better, which was obvious as I make a call to a function, NextEvent, which is thread blocking.

```
     let outerloop args dic = 
        ...
        let rec innerloop continuetoloop   =
           let eventObj = session.NextEvent();  //This blocks
            ...

     let seqtable = reader.ReadFile( @"C:\homeware\sector.csv", ";".[0], true) 

     let dic = ConcurrentDictionary<_,_> ()
     let wf = seqtable |> Seq.mapi (fun i item -> async { outerloop item dic } )
     wf  |> Async.Parallel
         |> Async.RunSynchronously
         |> ignore
     printfn "%A" ret
```

Is there a good way to wrap that blocking call to a **nonblocking** call ?
Also, why is the async framework not creating as many threads as I have requests (like 200)? when I inspect the threads from which I receive values I see only 4-5 that are used..

**UPDATE**

I found a compelling reason of why it will never be possible.
async operation take what is after the async instruction and schedule it somewhere in the threadpool.
for all that matters, as long as async function are use correctly, that is, always returning to the threadpool it originated from, we can consider that we are execution on a single thread.

Being on a single thread mean all that scheduling will always be executed somewhere later, and a blocking instruction has no way to avoid the fact that, eventually, once it runs, it will have to block at some point in the future the worflow.

Comment: How would creating 200 threads help you in any way? If you had 200 connection, you will have 200 very slow connections, instead of just a few fast ones. (Not mentioning the 200 MB of overhead.)

Comment: Also, if your operation is IO blocking, then using more CPU won't give you much benefit. It's slow because the network is slow and you won't make your network faster by using more threads.

Comment: @svick why wouldn't 200 slow connections be 40 times better than 5 slow connections for an IO bound computation ? I can see that it is processing 40 bunch of 5 operations now, which would be better served  by 1 bunch of 200 operations. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Because you're probably limited by your network. Using more threads won't make your network faster.

Comment: Oh you are saying each of the computation would go 40 times slower. I doubt it, because if I do a group retrieval, it is much faster. So it is mostly latency, more that bandwidth which limits my calls. So paying latency only once would definitely improve overall speed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good way to wrap that blocking call to a nonblocking call ?

No. You can never wrap blocking calls to make them non-blocking. If you could, async would just be a design pattern rather than a fundamental paradigm shift.

> Also, why is the async framework not creating as many threads as I have requests (like 200)?

Async is built upon the thread pool which is designed not to create threads aggressively because they are so expensive. The whole point of (real) async is that it does not require as many threads as there are connections. You can handle 10,000 simultaneous connections with ~30 threads.

You seem to have a complete misunderstanding of what async is and what it is for. I'd suggest buying any of the F# books that cover this topic and reading up on it. In particular, your solution is not asynchronous because you just call your blocking `StartGetFieldsValue` member from inside your async workflow, defeating the purpose of async. You might as well just do `Array.Parallel.map getFieldsValue` instead.

Also, you want to use a purely functional API when doing things in parallel rather than mutating a `ConcurrentDictionary` in-place. So replace `req.StartGetFieldsValue ret` with

```
let! result = req.StartGetFieldsValue()
...
return result
```

and replace `ignore` with `dict`.

Comment: I was not hoping for a solution using async for the first pb. as I read, asyncs are just CPS rewrite. (for the dictionary, it is possible, if not efficient for this particular API, to do a request for several securities, over several fields, and the info is coming bits by bits. what is the smallest unit that makes sense... there is probably a nice way to package it but I am not aware of it)

Comment: that being said, I will for sure read some more materials, because there must be a way to map this api nicely..

Comment: your remark made me think again on what are really async computations. and although we can say they are just CPS rewrite, this is just form the pov of code. the real story, if I am not wrong about this, is that async computations are for *threadpools* what sync computation are for *threads*. that is why they 'feel' like synchronous computations most of the time. threadpool, as you pointed out, being extremely useful for what we do 99% of the time, async constructs reflect that power.

Comment: Threadpools are part of how async in F# happens to have been implemented but the important difference is that async consumes minimal resources during IO operations whereas sync IO blocks threads and threads are very expensive for many reasons (1MB stack, OS scheduler stress etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I made that seems to be working.
Of course it does not use only async (minus a), but Async as well.

I define a simple type that has one event, finished, and one method, asyncstart, with the method to run as an argument. it launches the method, then fires the event finished at the appropriate place (in my case I had to capture the synchronization context etc..)

Then in the consumer side, I use simply

```
let! completion = Async.Waitfromevent wapper.finished |> Async.StartAsChild
let! completed = completion
```

While running this code, on the consumer side, I use only async calls, making my code non blocking. Of course, there has to be some thread somewhere which is blocked, but this happens outside of my main serving loop which remains reactive and fit.